# Converting data.frame into an edgelist to use in a chord diagram

Tags: r, chord-diagram, edge-list

I would like to create a chord diagram to showcase the relationship between different projects based on their keywords. So I have data that looks like this (where A, B, C represent keywords):

```
               A    B    C
Project  1     1    0    1 
Project  2     0    1    1 
Project  3     1    0    1
```

In order to create a chord diagram, I need to transform my data into an adjacency matrix or an edge list.

I have tried using igraph on the orignial dataset, but it expect an adjacency matrix and I cannot figure out how to convert the data.

The adjacency matrix would like something like this:

```
    A  B  C
A   -  0  1
B   0  -  1
C   2  1  -
```

The edge list would look something like this:

```
From  To
 A    C
 B    C
 A    C
```

The data has 60 keywords. 
What would you suggest has a solution for this issues?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

One way to create the edge list using `dplyr` and `tidyr` could be:

```
df %>%
 mutate_all(~ replace(., . == 0, NA)) %>%
 rowid_to_column() %>%
 pivot_longer(names_to = "variables", values_to = "values", -rowid, values_drop_na = TRUE) %>%
 group_by(rowid) %>%
 mutate(variables2 = if_else(row_number() == 1, "From", "To")) %>%
 ungroup() %>%
 select(-values) %>%
 pivot_wider(names_from = "variables2", values_from = "variables") %>%
 select(-rowid)

  From  To   
  <chr> <chr>
1 A     C    
2 B     C    
3 A     C
```